# How can I make Span children with text to layout to fit the width of the parent div tag?

Tags: html, css

In this example, I set the width of the div tag to be 200px and I want all the span children to be layout using the all the width of the parent div tag and take a second row of span tag if the first row is filled.

I tried to do that via this, but I only see all the span tags in 1 row:

```
<html>

<body>

<div width="200px">
<span> text 1 </span> <span> text 2 </span> <span> text 8 </span> <span> text 4 </span><span> text5 </span>
<span> text 6 </span><span> text 7 </span><span> text 9 </span><span> text 10 </span><span> text 11 </span>
<span> text 12 </span><span> text 18 </span> <span> text 14 </span><span> text15 </span>
<span> text 16 </span><span> text 17 </span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set `span` to `display: block;` and the `width: 100%;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` attribute is not a valid attribute for `div` elements. You should use css to set width or you can use inline style like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px"></div>
```

The following is a list of elements that can have `width` attribute;

```
<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>
```